# Simulation of generate scripts in SQL Server 2005+ (without using Management Studio)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any built-it stored procedure / any database program by which I can generate all the database object script (like stored procedures, triggers, functions, tables etc.) from a particular database?

I am using SQL Server 2005 + 2008

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS itself uses SMO, namely the [Scripter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) class. You can use SMO from any .Net application to extract scripts yourself.

Answer (score 0):

from .net
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated

from powershell
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1745

sqlcmd
http://www.edumax.com/microsoft-sql-server-the-sqlcmd-tool-and-sql-server-management-objects.html

Answer (score -1):

In Object Explorer in Microsoft Server Management Studio rightclick on the database and select Tasks -> Generate Script and then follow the guide...

Comment: I clearly wrote that I need to do the work using some spored procs and not by using SSMS tools

Comment: it's ok.. we all make mistake (: